# Seg Fault after declaring a big array

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

my problem is as follows:

This code returns a seg fault (core dumped):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double array[128][128][128];

  printf("done");

  return 1;
}
```

while this code is ok:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double array[128][128][128];

int main(void) {

  printf("done");

  return 1;
}
```

Of course is a problem of memory, because if I put inside the main function the declaration:

```
float array[127][128][128];
```

the code works well. On the other hand, if I use "malloc" for allocating the cube inside the main function, the code works well also.
I can not understand the reason for that. There is a simple explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct this is because when you are putting double `array[128][128][128];` inside the `main` then it is allocating more memory bytes on the stack which is not supported by your OS.

But when it allocated outside the `main` then it gets the memory from outside the application pool and hence you dont see any error.

Comment: I doubt that it's the OS, but rather the compiler settings. There is probably a compiler (or linker) switch to allow a larger stack.